# Unit Test Mongoose Promises

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I have an express route in a Node application that uses Mongoose for querying a Mongo database. There is a promise used in the `get` request to find items and I am not sure how to test this promise.

I am not very familiar with unit testing node applications.

Here is the code for the express route, this works but I am not sure how to test it:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var promise = require('bluebird');
// bluebird.promisifyAll is used on Mongoose in app.js
var ItemModel = require('./itemModel');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    ItemModel.findAsync()
        .then(function(items) {
            res.status(200).send(items);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            next(err);
        });

});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is what I have stubbed out in the test so far. I am not sure how to test the promise in the routes.get method :

```
describe('ItemRoute', function() {
    var express = require('express');
    var bodyParser = require('bodyParser');
    var supertest = require('supertest');
    var sinon = require('sinon');
    var expect = require('chai').expect;
    var assert = require('chai').assert;

    var ItemModel = require('./ItemModel');
    var ItemRoute = require('ItemRoute');

    var uri = '/items/';

    var agent;

    beforeEach(function(done) {
        var app = express();

        app.use(bodyParser.json());
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
        app.use(uri, releaseNotesRoute);

        agent = supertest.agent(app);

        done();
    });

    describe('GET', function() {
        it('returns an empty array when no items are stored in Mongo', function() {

            // Not sure how to test the route here with a get that
            // uses a promise, ItemModel.findAsync().then

        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Here's an article I wrote on testing promises with mocha http://catfish.life/testing-promises-with-mocha/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to able to use promises in test, you should have to install sinon-as-promises module from npm. Then you can mock ItemModel like this:

```
var itemModelMock = sinon.mock(ItemModel);
itemModelMock.expects('findAsync').resolves([]);
```

Comment: Is `itemModelMock.expects('findAsync').resolves([])` the expected return from the `ItemModel.findAsync.then()` call?

Comment: Yes, resolves use for then, `itemModelMock.expect('findAsync').rejects()` use for catch